# Amazon Connect & Salesforce: Lambda not working INVALID_SESSION_ID

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to integrate Amazon Connect with Salesforce using the packages made by AWS however when testing the lambda I receive the message INVALID_SESSION_ID. What I find really strange is why on the configuration of the connected app in Salesforce on the callback url according to the documentation we put https://www.salesforce.com. Shouldn't the callback come from aws? Anyhow as far as I can tell aws receives the token but when the lookup function is called the error comes up.

I'm using the following GitHub Links:

https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-salesforce-cti

https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-salesforce-lambda

Error log

```
bzKv+Pr6lGm1ZMLkacQKS5WbYCNhNebvoNNLfV2jrIpxVgBmmcXeLyc23esKnykozrac8iH/80pXG+KUo5oEkxYDCq8oP+BTrhAZ1y71czuki/V6VhFCplg4FckDdIDe4h7ZvA3ILUzKwqbc4zbvhibouOSgjIlhWLwDBi9eGrYzd/0Di0lYhbpV2Yo5dVmEJlPQuyZi/ic1I41lbtGwoGWcFQmGguQitIzpM4NN10OtJobbRbtG8g3rSsW1Xej0O1Scr4ZU5BMb4M71B9gM+Kop2u2LfF5diVX+6gMjZG5ih8ZcC0KRfLgsPhXy0r4uTrxu93ZsHmyVP/qhs+6PIS/yyAA3jX4b+tGSf/011LyIaecyuZGXauHKW+JVxmdSVNS+tALm8ZiYfWJw==', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIA44IUN6PRAVKNCAWZ/20201127/us-east-1/secretsmanager/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token;x-amz-target, Signature=916682f4825596db366ce6cf929b8651f7e9a989a84c1a22c965083f3f96487e', 'Content-Length': '631'}>

[DEBUG] 2020-11-27T13:03:41.748Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    https://secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 204

[DEBUG] 2020-11-27T13:03:41.749Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    Response headers: {'Date': 'Fri, 27 Nov 2020 13:03:41 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'Content-Length': '204', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-RequestId': '2d4e3e06-fe9a-4c72-a44a-1f38e361d1db'}

[DEBUG] 2020-11-27T13:03:41.749Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    Response body:
b'{"ARN":"arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:secret:SalesforceCredentials-azyPmX","Name":"SalesforceCredentials","VersionId":"fc66f8aa-1451-477e-996f-8647602318e4","VersionStages":["AWSCURRENT"]}'

[DEBUG] 2020-11-27T13:03:41.750Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    Event needs-retry.secrets-manager.PutSecretValue: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f93549229d0>

[DEBUG] 2020-11-27T13:03:41.750Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    No retry needed.

[INFO]  2020-11-27T13:03:41.791Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    Salesforce: Query

[INFO]  2020-11-27T13:03:41.791Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    POST Requests:
url=https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.lightning.force.com/services/data/v50.0/parameterizedSearch

[INFO]  2020-11-27T13:03:41.810Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    data={'q': '700929045', 'sobjects': [{'name': 'Contact'}], 'fields': ['Id', 'Name', 'Email']}
params=None

[DEBUG] 2020-11-27T13:03:41.812Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xxxxxxxxxxxxx.lightning.force.com:443

[DEBUG] 2020-11-27T13:03:42.432Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    https://xxxxxxxxx.lightning.force.com:443 "POST /services/data/v50.0/parameterizedSearch HTTP/1.1" 302 0

[DEBUG] 2020-11-27T13:03:42.451Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xxxxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com:443

[DEBUG] 2020-11-27T13:03:43.85Z 141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    https://xxxxxxxxx.my.salesforce.com:443 "GET /services/data/v50.0/parameterizedSearch HTTP/1.1" 401 None

[INFO]  2020-11-27T13:03:43.88Z 141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    Response: [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

[ERROR] 2020-11-27T13:03:43.110Z    141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270    INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid

[ERROR] Exception: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/sfInvokeAPI.py", line 55, in lambda_handler
    resp = phoneLookup(sf, event['Details']['Parameters']['sf_phone'], event['Details']['Parameters']['sf_fields'])
  File "/var/task/sfInvokeAPI.py", line 115, in phoneLookup
    records = sf.parameterizedSearch(data=data)
  File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 113, in parameterizedSearch
    resp = self.request.post(url=url, data=data, headers=self.headers)
  File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 204, in post
    return __check_resp__(r)
  File "/var/task/salesforce.py", line 239, in __check_resp__
    raise Exception(msg)
END RequestId: 141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270
REPORT RequestId: 141cea64-07ef-4d44-a028-f755806a2270  Duration: 3145.11 ms    Billed Duration: 3200 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB  Init Duration: 685.35 ms
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

after a lot of suffering the issue was the name of the SF_HOST declared in the lambda function.