# 401:Unauthorized [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

Tags: aws-lambda, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I'm trying to query salesforce records from Amazon Lambda function, and stuck with an error  401:Unauthorized [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]. Could anyone know the reason why this is happening?

Attached is the image of the configurations that are used
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5DPI.png)

I see the same issue as below thread, but I don't find an answer in that thread.
[Amazon Connect & Salesforce: Lambda not working INVALID_SESSION_ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65038265/amazon-connect-salesforce-lambda-not-working-invalid-session-id)